# Multiple delayed QTimer::singleShot calls triggers all Slots immediately

Tags: qt, qtimer

I have > 1 _services with which I want to do something in the function "performCheck(...)". This performCheck function *should* be called delayed for each service by 1s the very first time. However, if I have e.g. 3 services (_services), performCheck is called *immediately* for all 3 services, instead of delayed.

Does anyone know, why this happens all at once (I (currently) have only the main QThread in which the QTimer is running).

Example Code:

```
int timeoutMs = 0;
for(auto& serviceContainer : _services) {
    Q_DEBUG_M() << "Perform check for " << serviceContainer.service->getServiceTypeDescription() << " in " << timeoutMs << "ms";

    serviceContainer.checkOngoing = true;
    QTimer::singleShot(timeoutMs, this, [this, &serviceContainer]() {
        performCheck(serviceContainer);
    });
    timeoutMs+=1000;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure *all* callbacks are triggered immediately?  I would expect the first one to be called as soon as you return to the event loop (it has a zero timeout) but not the remaining ones.  If possible please provide a [mcve].

Comment: So, it works now. Basically our application is quiet bit and needs a bit to initialize everything in the beginning (GUI App). 

I call the above code very early in a Constructor, then registered all QML types, etc. If I call the above code *after* registering all QML types, etc. it starts at the correct delays, and not all at once (although delays are set).

So I think, that somehow the event queue is not initialized at that point. I will investigate it more deeply, but moving the call of the above code a bit later during initialization seems to fix the problem.

Comment: Please consider Upvoting and accepting an answer when it was helpful to you and answered your question

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out in your comment and your question it depends on the EventQueue (EventLoop).
When a `QTimer` times out (regardless of singleshot or normal timer) the triggered SLOT will be pushed to the EventQueue and processed. Now since you only have the main Thread running you only have one EventQueue (QTimers will trigger also if the EventQueue is blocked).

Now in your case imaginge something blocks the main thread with something (like the init of the QML Stuff) for more than 3 seconds. Therefore your EventQueue stops for more than 3 seconds. But the QTimer happily pushes the SLOTs to be triggered in the Queue. Now after unblocking the thread the EventQueue processing continues, and it will process all the SLOTs pushed by the QTimer "immediatly".

The easy solution is for you that you perform your checks after init. If that works for you thats fine. Otherwise consider writing a async check for your services via `QThread`. A QThread has its own EventLoop (Queue). So you can perform your checks on time and just report the results, which will be fetched when the main thread is responding again. I hope this clears things up for you.